# Regex string but with several options

Tags: c#, regex

My string:

```
string str = "user:steo id:1 nickname|user:kevo id:2 nickname:kevo200|user:noko id:3 nickname";
```

Now I want to get the values out with Regex:

```
var reg = Regex.Matches(str, @"user:(.+?)\sid:(\d+)\s+nickname:(.+?)")
          .Cast<Match>()
          .Select(a => new
          {
              user = a.Groups[1].Value,
              id = a.Groups[2].Value,
              nickname = a.Groups[3].Value
           })
           .ToList();
foreach (var ca in reg)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ca.user} id: {ca.id} nickname: {ca.nickname}");
}
```

I do not know how I can do it with regex that I can use `nickname:(the nickname)`  I only want use the nickname if it has a nickname like `nickname:kevo200` and noch `nickname`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the structure of the string. Does it always contain the field `nickname`, but the value for nickname may be empty? If the `nickname` is empty is this denoted as `nickkname|` or `nickname:|` What do you want to do with users, which don't have a nickname?

Comment: A plus sign indicates one or more while an asterisk indicates zero or more.  I would replace the +? with *.  I think it is better to use \w* where 'w' is a word character instead of the do which is every character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**: `user:(.+?)\sid:(\d+)\s+nickname:*(.*?)(\||$)`.

At first I proposed this regex: `user:(.+?)\sid:(\d+)\s+nickname:*(.*?)\|*` – wrong, doesn't capture name because of lazy quantifier.

Then this regex expression: `user:(.+?)\sid:(\d+)\s+nickname(:(.+?)|)(\||$)` – this should match all the parts divided by '|' in your string and give nickname="" for empty nicknames. But in case `Groups[4]` is not defined (when nickname is not followed by ":") you'll need check on the value existence.

Comment: `*` denotes "0 or more". Do you expect the string to look like "nickname::::::" or "nickname:abc|||||||||"?

Comment: Based on the above example, the `:` after `nickname` is only present, when there is a value for nickname. Furthermore, the `*` is a greedy operator, so at least the last one will match anything after the first user ...

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Of course not, though it all depends on user input check. I assumed avoid using (:|) and (\||) constructions to correct and clear grouping.

Comment: Your answer is not far from the solution, but now I can not get the content out of the nickname: https://regexr.com/3ufbk

Comment: @mariaLynx though you've found the solution, I have made some update. But it is still not pure regex solution.

Comment: And another update, seems to work as pure regex solution, see answer.

Comment: I'd use `nickname:?` instead of `nickname:*`

Answer (score 1):

I am not a 100% sure if this answers your question, but i fetched a list from the given input string via regex parsing and either return the nick when available or the username otherwise.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> scriptcs
> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
> var regex = new Regex(@"\|?(?:user(?::?(?<user>\w+))\sid(?::?(?<id>\d*))\s?nickname(?::?(?<nick>\w+))?)");
> var matches = regex.Matches("user:steo id:1 nickname|user:kevo id:2 nickname:kevo200|user:noko id:3 nickname");
> matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m=>new {user=m.Groups["user"].Value,nick=m.Groups["nick"].Value}).Select(u=>string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(u.nick)?u.user:u.nick);
[
  "steo",
  "kevo200",
  "noko"
]
```

edit: regex designer: https://regexr.com/3uf8t

edit: improved version to accept escape sequences in nicknames

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> scriptcs
> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
> var regex = new Regex(@"\|?(?:user(?::(?<user>\w+))?\sid(?::(?<id>\d*))?\s?nickname(?::(?<nick>[\w\\]+))?)");
> var matches = regex.Matches("user:steo id:1 nickname|user:kevo id:2 nickname:kevo200|user:noko id:3 nickname|user:kevo id:2 nickname:kev\\so200");
> matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m=>new {user=m.Groups["user"].Value,nick=m.Groups["nick"].Value.Replace("\\s"," ")}).Select(u=>string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(u.nick)?u.user:u.nick);
[
  "steo",
  "kevo200",
  "noko",
  "kev o200"
]
```

Comment: if the nickname has a `\s` it does not work example: `nickname:stev\shans` the `\s` is a whitespace I think its the `\w+`

Comment: when this is your only escape sequence, this should work:
`\|?(?:user(?::?(?<user>\w+))\sid(?::?(?<id>\d*))\s?nickname(?::?(?<nick>[\w\\]+))?)`
you have to replace it in the nickname afterwards of cause...
it will also work with other `\\` prefixed escapes...

Answer (score 0):

If it were up to me and the data you are processing is always pipe separated and in a constant order, I would probably just skip the regex and split the string into it's pieces using [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) like this.

```
string str = "user:steo id:1 nickname|user:kevo id:2 nickname:kevo200|user:noko id:3 nickname";
var entries = str.Split('|');
foreach(var entry in entries)
{
    var subs = entry.Split(' ');
    var userName = subs[0].Split(':')[1];
    var id = subs[1].Split(':')[1];
    var tempNick = subs[2].Split(':');
    var nick = tempNick.Length == 2 ? tempNick[1] : string.Empty;
    Console.WriteLine(userName + " id:" + id + " nickname " + nick);
}
```

Comment: Oops! Didn't see your answer! I've packed everything into more readable LINQ. :)

Comment: @JohnyL - I might argue on the "packed" and "readability" side since you accomplished in 15 lines what I did in 8 ;)

Comment: Well, you cheated a bit) For instance, anonymous type creation could be done in one line. Indeed, I could write all the code in one line. How many semicolons do you have? :) :) The thing is that my code is functional, but yours - procedural. You extract data and output at the same time, while my code could be packed into separate method. To summarize, getting data and outputting it could take two lines. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without Regex:

```
static void GetInfo()
{
    string input = @"user:steo id:1 nickname|user:kevo id:2 nickname:kevo200|user:noko id:3 nickname";

    var users =
        from info in input.Split('|')
        let x = info.Split(" ")
        let nick_split = x[2].Split(':')
        let has_nick = nick_split.GetUpperBound(0) > 0
        let z = new
        {
            User = x[0].Split(':')[1],
            Id = x[1].Split(':')[1],
            Nickname = has_nick ? nick_split[1] : String.Empty
        }
        select z;

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"user: {user.User}, id: {user.Id}, nickname: {user.Nickname}");
    }

}
```